# Pandas Python - Comparing different date ranges and checking if they are in the same time period

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datatable

I am currently solving a problem and was recommended to use 'Pandas', as it would fit for my solution, so my apologies, as I am kind of new to the 'Pandas' package.

The problem I am trying to solve is to read a text file with data such as this:

```
EmpID,ProjectID,DateFrom,DateTo
1,100,2014-11-01,2015-05-01
2,101,2013-12-06,2014-10-06
3,102,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
5,103,2014-10-01,2015-12-01
2,100,2013-03-07,2015-11-07
2,103,2015-07-09,2019-01-19
4,102,2013-11-13,2014-03-13
4,103,2016-02-14,2017-03-15
5,104,2014-03-15,2015-11-09
```

Now my task was to say which employees worked together the longest time period on a common project.

This is my progress so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

date_parser = lambda c: pd.to_datetime(c, format='%Y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter = ',', parse_dates=[2,3], date_parser=date_parser)
#df.set_index("EmpID", inplace = True)
df.sort_values(['ProjectID'], inplace=True)
df['Days Worked'] = (df['DateTo'] - df['DateFrom']).dt.days
cutdown_projecs = df.groupby('ProjectID').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)

print(cutdown_projecs)
```

What I do is order the table, make the date values the correct format, sort by ProjectID and then cut down to projects that repeat themselves two or more times (as this would mean employees worked together on them). I also added a new column, which adds "Days Worked". Which leads me to the following result:

```
     EmpID  ProjectID   DateFrom     DateTo      Days Worked
0      1        100    2014-11-01 2015-05-01          181
4      2        100    2013-03-07 2015-11-07          975
2      3        102    2015-06-04 2017-09-04          823
6      4        102    2013-11-13 2014-03-13          120
3      5        103    2014-10-01 2015-12-01          426
5      2        103    2015-07-09 2019-01-19         1290
7      4        103    2016-02-14 2017-03-15          395
```

Now, I am in need of advice as to how to approach the problem correctly. I somehow need to check, which data ranges 'collide' on the same project and then calculate the working days of the employees together. I would very much appreciate it if you could give me a tip. Thank you.

EDIT: Fixed the table.

Comment: Do you want to know that for every pair of EmpID or for all EmpID in a project? What's your expect output for the toy dataset above?

Comment: @QuangHoang I just want to know for the pair of EmpID that has the longest project work time together. I just noticed that the table has been messed up from formatting and I will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cobbled up a solution, but don't know if it meets your needs. It gets the longest time worked together on a job by 2 employees.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
from datetime import datetime

data ='''\
1,100,2014-11-01,2015-05-01
2,101,2013-12-06,2014-10-06
3,102,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
5,103,2014-10-01,2015-12-01
2,100,2013-03-07,2015-11-07
2,103,2015-07-09,2019-01-19
4,102,2013-11-13,2014-03-13
4,103,2016-02-14,2017-03-15
5,104,2014-03-15,2015-11-09'''.splitlines()

d = defaultdict(list)
for line in data:
    empID, job, start, finish = line.split(',')
    d[job].append([empID,start,finish])

for job, aref in d.items():
    if len(aref) >= 2:
        for ref in combinations(aref, 2):
            begin = max(map(lambda x: x[1], ref))
            end = min(map(lambda x: x[2], ref))
            delta = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d') \
                    - datetime.strptime(begin, '%Y-%m-%d')
            dd = delta.days
            if dd > 0:
                print('employees', ref[0][0], 'and', ref[1][0],
                      'worked together', dd, 'days on job', job)
```

Output was:

```
employees 1 and 2 worked together 181 days on job 100
employees 5 and 2 worked together 145 days on job 103
employees 2 and 4 worked together 395 days on job 103
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a great solution, and I think I wasted a couple of hours on pandas (but it's still time not wasted!). I will just try to adapt your code, make it read data from a .csv/.txt (instead of the data variable you have), which I hope would be easy enough to make. I am also wondering if there is a way for the code to accept  "NULL" as today's date. Thank you again!!!

Comment: @Gergan Zhekov Glad it was of use to you! I edited the code to one case, `if len(aref) >= 2:` and got the same results as the original attempt. I am not sure how to handle `NULL`. I've not worked with `pandas`, but it looks like a shorter solution (from your code).