# Pair of employees that worked together for the longest period of time - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datatables, combinations

I recently had to do a code, which returns the pair of employees that have worked the most together on a common project. This is the code I came up with:

Note 1: Null is read by the program as "Today"

Note 2: The data comes from a .txt file in this form:

```
EmpID,ProjectID,DateFrom,DateTo
1,101,2014-11-01,2015-05-01
1,103,2013-11-01,2016-05-01
2,101,2013-12-06,2014-10-06
2,103,2014-06-05,2015-05-14
3,100,2016-03-01,2018-07-03
3,102,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
3,103,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
4,102,2013-11-13,2014-03-13
4,103,2016-02-14,2017-03-15
4,104,2014-10-01,2015-12-01
5,100,2013-03-07,2015-11-07
5,101,2015-07-09,2019-01-19
5,102,2014-03-15,NULL
6,101,2014-03-15,2014-03-16
```

The problem that I currently have is that I have to adapt/change the code to return the pair of employees that have worked together with each other the longest (not on a single project, but all projects combined). I am having troubles of adapting my current code, which runs perfectly fine for what it is, and I am wondering if I should just scratch all of this and start from the beginning (but it would cost me a lot of time, which I don't have currently). I am having difficulties with obtaining the combinations of employees that have worked together on projects.

I would very much appreciate it if anyone can give me any tips! Thanks!

Edit 1: A person in the comments reminded me to mention that overlapping days should be counted as for example:

Person A and B work on two projects for the entirety of June. This means that it should be counted as 30 days total common work (for the two projects), not adding both project times together, which would result in 60 days.

Comment: Should overlapping days on different projects be counted, or ignored? I.e. if Person 1 and 2 both work on Projects A and B for all of June, do they have 30 or 60 days worked together?

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for the heads up, I will add this to the post. For your example, this would mean 30 days (as they worked together only for the whole month of June).

Comment: how does this question differ from your [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367256/pandas-python-comparing-different-date-ranges-and-checking-if-they-are-in-the)? It helps if you refer it for the context.

Comment: Also, roughly how many projects and employees are we talking about? That makes certain things more or less feasible

Comment: The other one greatly helped me reach the solution for my previous task (longest working pair on a common project). Now the task is different and I have to adapt my current code, and it would not be enough (or at least I haven't figured it out yet). @ALollz Look at the example .txt file in the post. This is roughly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one of the more straight-forward ways I can think of doing this.

1. Expand the timespans to a single row per date.
2. Merge all Days on the same project (to get all combinations of people who worked together)
3. Remove duplicated rows of people who work together on the same day, but different projects.
4. Just find how many rows are within each worker pairing.

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def expand_period_daily(df, start, stop):
    # Allows it to work for one day spans. 
    df.loc[df[stop].notnull(), stop] = (df.loc[df[stop].notnull(), stop] 
                                        + pd.Timedelta(hours=1))

    real_span = df[[start, stop]].notnull().all(1)

    # Resample timespans to daily fields. 
    df['temp_id'] = range(len(df))
    dailydf = (df.loc[real_span, ['temp_id', start, stop]].set_index('temp_id').stack()
                 .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True).rename('period').to_frame())
    dailydf = (dailydf.groupby('temp_id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('period')
                      .resample('d').asfreq()).reset_index())

    # Merge back other information
    dailydf = (dailydf.merge(df, on=['temp_id'])
                      .drop(columns=['temp_id', start, stop]))

    return dailydf
```

---

```
# Make dates, fill missings.
df[['DateFrom', 'DateTo']] = df[['DateFrom', 'DateTo']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
df[['DateFrom', 'DateTo']] = df[['DateFrom', 'DateTo']].fillna(pd.to_datetime('today').normalize())

dailydf = expand_period_daily(df.copy(), start='DateFrom', stop='DateTo')

# Merge, remove rows of employee with him/herself.
m = (dailydf.merge(dailydf, on=['period', 'ProjectID'])
            .loc[lambda x: x.EmpID_x != x.EmpID_y])

# Ensure A-B and B-A are grouped the same
m[['EmpID_x', 'EmpID_y']] = np.sort(m[['EmpID_x', 'EmpID_y']].to_numpy(), axis=1)

# Remove duplicated projects on same date between employee pairs
m = m.drop_duplicates(['period', 'EmpID_x', 'EmpID_y'])

m.groupby(['EmpID_x', 'EmpID_y']).size().to_frame('Days_Together')
```

#### Output:

```
                 Days_Together
EmpID_x EmpID_y               
1       2                  344
        3                  333
        4                   78
2       6                    2
3       4                  396
        5                  824
```

---

#### Test Case

To give a bit more clarity on how it handles overlaps, and combines different projects, Here's the following test case:

```
   EmpID  ProjectID   DateFrom     DateTo
0      1        101 2014-11-01 2014-11-15
1      1        103 2014-11-01 2014-11-15
2      1        105 2015-11-02 2015-11-03
3      2        101 2014-11-01 2014-11-15
4      2        103 2014-11-01 2014-11-15
5      2        105 2015-10-02 2015-11-05
6      3        101 2014-11-01 2014-11-15
```

Employees 1 and 2 perfectly overlap for 15 days on 2 projects in Nov 2014. They then work together for 2 additional days on another project in 2015. 1, 2 and 3 all work together for 15 days on a single Project.

Running with this test case we obtain:

```
                 Days_Together
EmpID_x EmpID_y               
1       2                   17
        3                   15
2       3                   15
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposed solution! I like how all possible pairings (and duplicates are deleted - just learned this great functionality of pandas!) are structured in the table and I think I only need a small panda function to show the max value from the Days_Together column as an output (which is easy to do), and it would work perfectly. I just have one small question, Days_Together considers multiple projects right - for example, 1 and 2 work on Project A and Project B together in different time periods, but their total work time is combined in this specific cell? Thank you again

Comment: @GerganZhekov Days_Together is the number of unique Days those two people worked together, and does not double count the same day for which they worked together on different projects, but pool the days across all possible projects. I updated the solution with a test-case that should clarify how this is handled.

Comment: Hey again! I think there might be an error in the drop_duplicates line, as I tried multiple times and the dataframe doesn't drop the extra rows (which are in the thousands). I tried putting the information in a subset, and then 'keep = False', but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @GerganZhekov that is odd. In the test case it's clearly dropping the duplicates (as 1 and 2 work together on 2 projects on the same days) so if it weren't dropping them you'd get 32 days, instead of 17.