# Find pair of employees that have worked together the longest on common project

Tags: javascript, performance

Kind of a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496199/pair-of-employees-that-worked-together-for-the-longest-period-of-time-python-p) but not at the same time because it's in python so I'm reposting it. The outputs are different as well for the same inputs.

Got a complicated assignment that I finally managed to solve but the algorithm I came up with is quite slow.
I'm pretty sure its around n^2 + n in worst case scenario.

It's supposed to go through a list of employees and return a list of employee pairs that have accumulated the most days worked together on common projectS. (the s is important)

Format for input:
EmployeeID, ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate(NULL === today)

Example input:

```
1,1,2019-7-4,2020-8-14
1,2,2019-12-25,2020-12-28
1,3,2018-10-12,NULL
1,4,2019-11-16,NULL
1,5,2020-1-5,2020-12-21
2,1,2018-10-3,NULL
2,2,2019-1-16,2020-3-24
2,3,2019-5-22,2019-12-26
2,4,2020-3-7,NULL
2,5,2018-1-24,2019-1-15
3,1,2019-3-21,2020-11-26
3,5,2019-9-28,2020-12-25
4,2,2018-10-22,NULL
4,3,2018-1-27,2020-8-28
5,3,2018-2-3,2020-10-14
5,5,2018-8-4,NULL
```

Format for output:
Employee#1, Employee#2, CommonProjectID, DaysWorked

Example output:

```
1,2,1,407
1,2,2,90
1,2,3,219
1,2,4,513
```

Here's my take on it but as I said it's quite slow and I was asked to try to optimize it. Been working on this for 5 hours now and can't come up with anything better.

```js
export default function getHighestPair(empl) {
  console.log(empl);
  let pairs = {};
  let daysTogether = {};
  if (empl)
    empl.forEach((el1) => {
      /*
        .slice() is used to exclude the current employee and employees before him
        from the search which slightly reduces complexity. This is because
        employee 5 + employee 13 is the same as employee 13 + employee 5
      */
      empl.slice(empl.indexOf(el1) + 1, empl.length).forEach((el2) => {
        // get start and end date of each of employee
        if (el1[0] !== el2[0]) {
          const startDate1 = new Date(el1[2]);
          const endDate1 = el1[3] === "NULL" ? new Date() : new Date(el1[3]);
          const startDate2 = new Date(el2[2]);
          const endDate2 = el2[3] === "NULL" ? new Date() : new Date(el2[3]);

          // check if they are in the same team (working on the same project)
          if (el1[1] === el2[1]) {
            if (startDate1 <= endDate2 && startDate2 <= endDate1) {
              // calculate the start and end day that we need
              const start = startDate1 <= startDate2 ? startDate2 : startDate1;
              const end = endDate1 <= endDate2 ? endDate1 : endDate2;
              if (end >= startDate2) {
                // put them inside this formula and we get the time they have worked together in days
                const diffTime = Math.abs(end - start);
                const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                const x = `${el1[0]}${el2[0]}`;

                if (!daysTogether[x]) Object.assign(daysTogether, { [x]: 0 });
                daysTogether[x] = 1 * daysTogether[x] + diffDays;

                if (!pairs[x]) Object.assign(pairs, { [x]: [] });
                pairs[x] = [...pairs[x], [el1[0], el2[0], el1[1], diffDays]];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  /*
    gets the index of the pair that have worked together the longest toghether from
    "daysTogether" which keeps count of the days for each project
  */
  return pairs[
    Object.keys(daysTogether).reduce((a, b) =>
      daysTogether[a] > daysTogether[b] ? a : b
    )
  ];
}
```

Comment: It might be much faster if you calculate the working time once before or you other calculations

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff how can I go about calculating the working time before everything else? I don't really get what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should be O(n log n).

for each record

- group record by project id
- for each stored record in this group, compare to current record

  - compare the worked together time to the longest for this group, if it's greater update longest
- add current record to stored records in this group

The deObjectify cleanup is not strictly necessary

```js
const data = [
  [1,2,"2019-12-25","2020-12-28"],
  [1,3,"2018-10-12",null],
  [1,4,"2019-11-16",null],
  [1,5,"2020-1-5","2020-12-21"],
  [2,1,"2018-10-3",null],
  [2,2,"2019-1-16","2020-3-24"],
  [2,3,"2019-5-22","2019-12-26"],
  [2,4,"2020-3-7",null],
  [2,5,"2018-1-24","2019-1-15"],
  [3,1,"2019-3-21","2020-11-26"],
  [3,5,"2019-9-28","2020-12-25"],
  [4,2,"2018-10-22",null],
  [4,3,"2018-1-27","2020-8-28"],
  [5,3,"2018-2-3","2020-10-14"],
  [5,5,"2018-8-4",null]
];

const overlap = (e1d1, e1d2, e2d1, e2d2) => {

  const startDate1 = new Date(e1d1);
  const endDate1 = e1d2 === null ? new Date() : new Date(e1d2);
  const startDate2 = new Date(e2d1);
  const endDate2 = e2d2 === null ? new Date() : new Date(e2d2);

  const start = startDate1 < startDate2 ? startDate2 : startDate1;
  const end = endDate1 < endDate2 ? endDate1 : endDate2;

  if (end >= start) {
    const diffTime = Math.abs(end - start);
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return diffDays;
  }
  
  return 0;
};

const result = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  let c = acc[el[1]];
  if (!c) {
    c = acc[el[1]] = {
      overlap: 0,
      e1: 0,
      e2: 0,
      data: []
    };
  };
  
  c.data.forEach(d => {
    const o = overlap(d[2], d[3], el[2], el[3]);
    if (o > c.overlap) {
      c.overlap = o;
      c.e1 = d[0];
      c.e2 = el[0];
    }
  });
  
  c.data.push(el);
  return acc;

}, {});

const deObjectify = Object.entries(result).map(([projectId, {e1, e2, overlap}]) => ({e1, e2, projectId, overlap}));

console.log(deObjectify);

console.log("inner workings");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Really interesting solution but I don't think you get what I'm trying to achieve. The result you are giving contains the longest overlap in a given project. What we want is employee pairs (pair means overlap() returns something other than 0) that have the biggest overlap on. 
When we get the overlaps per pair we sum the days and see which pair has the most days and return it. 
If these is the final list of pairs we get after overlap we want to return only the first two because they sum to 300 days and the last one is only 250.  
1,2,1,100 
1,2,2,200 
2,5,3,250 
I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

So this is my final code...

Result:

```
[ { emA: 1, emB: 2, sum: 1230, details: [{ proj: 1, days: 407 }, { proj: 2, days:  90 }, { proj: 3, days: 219 }, { proj: 4, days: 514 }]} 
, { emA: 1, emB: 5, sum: 1084, details: [{ proj: 3, days: 733 }, { proj: 5, days: 351 }]} 
, { emA: 1, emB: 4, sum: 1055, details: [{ proj: 2, days: 369 }, { proj: 3, days: 686 }]} 
, { emA: 4, emB: 5, sum:  937, details: [{ proj: 3, days: 937 }                        ]} 
, { emA: 1, emB: 3, sum:  758, details: [{ proj: 1, days: 407 }, { proj: 5, days: 351 }]} 
, { emA: 2, emB: 4, sum:  652, details: [{ proj: 2, days: 433 }, { proj: 3, days: 219 }]} 
, { emA: 2, emB: 3, sum:  616, details: [{ proj: 1, days: 616 }                        ]} 
, { emA: 3, emB: 5, sum:  455, details: [{ proj: 5, days: 455 }                        ]} 
, { emA: 2, emB: 5, sum:  384, details: [{ proj: 3, days: 219 }, { proj: 5, days: 165 }]} 
]
```

```js
const data = 
  [ [ 1, 1, '2019-7-4',   '2020-8-14'  ]
  , [ 1, 2, '2019-12-25', '2020-12-28' ]  // EmployeeID, ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate(null === today)
  , [ 1, 3, '2018-10-12',  null        ]
  , [ 1, 4, '2019-11-16',  null        ]
  , [ 1, 5, '2020-1-5',   '2020-12-21' ]
  , [ 2, 1, '2018-10-3',   null        ]
  , [ 2, 2, '2019-1-16',  '2020-3-24'  ]
  , [ 2, 3, '2019-5-22',  '2019-12-26' ]
  , [ 2, 4, '2020-3-7',    null        ]
  , [ 2, 5, '2018-1-24',  '2019-1-15'  ]
  , [ 3, 1, '2019-3-21',  '2020-11-26' ]
  , [ 3, 5, '2019-9-28',  '2020-12-25' ]
  , [ 4, 2, '2018-10-22',  null        ]
  , [ 4, 3, '2018-1-27',  '2020-8-28'  ]
  , [ 5, 3, '2018-2-3',   '2020-10-14' ]
  , [ 5, 5, '2018-8-4',    null        ]
  ]

const
  oneDay  = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
, setDate = YMD =>
    {
    let [Y,M,D] = YMD.split('-').map(Number)
    return new Date(Y,--M,D)
    }

// group Employees by project id , change date string to JS newDate

const Proj_Emps = data.reduce( (r,[EmployeeID, ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate])=>
  {
  let stD = setDate(StartDate)
    , enD = EndDate ? setDate(EndDate) :  new Date()
  r[ProjectID] = r[ProjectID] ?? []
  r[ProjectID].push({EmployeeID,stD,enD})
  return r
  }, {})
// combination of pairs of employees per project 

let combination = {}
for (let proj in Proj_Emps) 
for (let i = 0; i < Proj_Emps[proj].length - 1; i++) 
for (let j = i + 1; j < Proj_Emps[proj].length; j++) 
  {
  let emA = Proj_Emps[proj][i]
  let emB = Proj_Emps[proj][j]

  if (( emA.enD <= emB.enD && emA.enD > emB.stD )
    ||( emB.enD <= emA.enD && emB.enD > emA.stD )
    ){
    let 
      D1   = emA.stD > emB.stD ? emA.stD : emB.stD
    , D2   = emA.enD < emB.enD ? emA.enD : emB.enD
    , days = Math.ceil((D2 - D1) / oneDay)
    , key  = `${emA.EmployeeID}-${emB.EmployeeID}`
      ;
    combination[key] = combination[key] ?? { emA: emA.EmployeeID, emB: emB.EmployeeID, sum:0, details:[] }
    combination[key].details.push({proj: Number(proj), days })
    combination[key].sum += days
    }
  } 
 
let Result  =  
  Object.entries(combination)
  .sort((a,b)=> b[1].sum - a[1].sum )
  .map(([k,v])=>v)

Result.forEach(el => console.log( JSON.stringify(el).replaceAll('"','')))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important; }
```

*I also fixed a bugg (typo) on the calculation of dates*

Comment: That's correct, Em 2 and Em 5 do have 1094 (or 1093 if you don't count today) but they are still not the highest pair. That is because Em 1 and Em 2 have 407 + 90 + 219 + 513 which is 1229 day together and therefore they are the result we are looking for.
Another thing I noticed is that you don't count all pairs, Em 1 and Em 2 have worked on Prj 1 for 407 days together and so on.

Comment: @IvailoHristov I updated my answer ... (not sure what to think about performance ...)

Comment: great way of solving it and the code seems(?) cleaner but yeah it's in no way faster than mine. I think I'll clean my code up a bit and submit it and just say I couldn't manage to optimize it but if it's possible I'd love to know how.